# Issue connecting to IRC Server

Tags: c++, irc, twitch

Been working on creating an IRC bot recently, and while it seems to connect & work with most IRC servers, it seems to have issues with the Twitch IRC server (irc.twitch.tv).

When connecting to another server, data is received & sent without any issues, however with the twitch connection, I can't send or receive data.

Initialize:

```
Connection::Connection(char* server, int port, std::string nick, std::string pass)
{
    fServer = server;
    fPort = port;
    fNick = nick;
    fPass = pass;
    fChanCount = 0;

    clear_buffer();

    fSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    cout << "Attempting to resolve host: " << fServer << endl;
    fHost = resolve_host(fServer);
    fSaddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = fHost;
    fSaddr.sin_port = htons(fPort);
    fSaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    cout << "Resolved to: " << fHost << endl;
}
```

Open Connection:

```
int Connection::Connect()
{
    if (connect(fSock, (sockaddr*)&fSaddr, sizeof(fSaddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "Can't connect to " << fServer << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    recv(fSock, fBuffer, 1024 * 8, 0);

    cout << fBuffer << endl << endl << flush;

    send_message("PASS " + fPass);
    send_message("NICK " + fNick);
    send_message("USER " + fNick + " 0 * :" + fNick);

    return 1;
}
```

Clear Buffer:

```
void Connection::clear_buffer()
{
    memset(fBuffer, 0, sizeof(fBuffer));
}
```

Receive:

```
string Connection::receive_message()
{
    clear_buffer();

    recv(fSock, fBuffer, 1024 * 8, 0);

    return fBuffer;
}
```

Completely stumped on what could be causing this, can provide more detail if needed.

Comment: Is `fPass` empty? IIRC some IRC servers require `PASS` to contain something even if the server does not require a password. I have put "none" for the password in that case.

Comment: I pass through the password in the same way as everything else.

Comment: Are you using the real password, or the OAuth token?

Answer (score 0):

Your USER message does not look like what the RFC2812 spec is asking for.

```
3.1.3 User message

      Command: USER
   Parameters: <user> <mode> <unused> <realname>

   The USER command is used at the beginning of connection to specify
   the username, hostname and realname of a new user.

   The <mode> parameter should be a numeric, and can be used to
   automatically set user modes when registering with the server.  This
   parameter is a bitmask, with only 2 bits having any signification: if
   the bit 2 is set, the user mode 'w' will be set and if the bit 3 is
   set, the user mode 'i' will be set.  (See Section 3.1.5 "User
   Modes").

   The <realname> may contain space characters.

   Numeric Replies:

           ERR_NEEDMOREPARAMS              ERR_ALREADYREGISTRED

   Example:

   USER guest 0 * :Ronnie Reagan   ; User registering themselves with a
                                   username of "guest" and real name
                                   "Ronnie Reagan".

   USER guest 8 * :Ronnie Reagan   ; User registering themselves with a
                                   username of "guest" and real name
                                   "Ronnie Reagan", and asking to be set
                                   invisible.
```

Perhaps that's what is causing the problem?

Otherwise I have found some servers require a password in the `PASS` message even if the server is not configured to require one. In those cases I send:

```
PASS none
```

Comment: I pass through the password in the same way as the server/port/user, so I don't think that is the issue. I also tried changing the USER message to fit the RFC2812 standard, still with no success.

Comment: @user3815037 Does your `clear_buffer()` function fill the buffer with zeros? Also do you take into account the line endings are LFCR ("\r\n")?

Comment: clear_buffer() simply calls memset() on the buffer, and fills it with zeros. As for sending messages, it does append "\r\n" to the end. It seems to work fine on other IRC servers, just not irc.twitch.tv.